INITIALIZE PACKED-DECIMAL field on DB2 Query
I'm using a PACKED-DECIMAL field COMP-3 on the WHERE clause on a DB2 QUERY.
When i initialize the zone and i want to display it: It shows: 0404040404
==> It means that the field contains LOW-VALUE
SQLCODE returns a code 0031è
How can i initialize this field to avoid this SQLCODE ?

What is the exact definition of your COMP-3 field?  x'04040404' does not look right to me for packed decimal.  Should end in a F if unsigned, D if signed and negative, or C if signed and positive.
Also does not look like low values. To me for a COMP-3 low values would be the number zero, so I would expect x'0000000F'.  I added "F" to show an unsigned number.

'040404040' means the field currently contains space characters.
Simply "MOVE +0 TO field-name " to set it to zero.

0404040404 is not LOW-VALUES, it is SPACES. You can do the following to change that and hopefully get your query to pass.
MOVE LOW-VALUES TO VARIABLE-NAME

